# SSRS Report using an aggregate expression in an IF clause?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have 1 data set with an aggregate function that takes a bunch of test scores and averages them out. I want to then take that result and if it's below 65% to change a text box to a certain text, example "Test scores low". I've tried using a variable but it errors out saying I can't use an aggregate function with a variable. What is the best way of doing this? I don't need a complete answer, just someone to point me in what method I should use.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to use the variable?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have already tried this. Set the value of the text box you wish to change the value of depends on the condition to use SSRS Expression

Use the SSRS expression for `Avg(expression, scope, recursive)` inside of `IFF(expression, value if expression equals true, value if expression equals false)`

looks something like this:

```
IIF(Avg(Fields!Testscore.Value, "mydataset") > .65 , "the average is larger than 65", "the average is lower than 65")
```

(you would have to replace `mydataset` with your dataset and `!Testscore.Value` to use the right column value. also, replace the text with the text you desire to change to.)